# embedded generator expressions

Tags: python

I have the following "embedded" generator expression:

```
words = ["a", "ab", "abc"]
for a in (y for y in words if len(y) >= len(x) for x in (b for b in words)):
    print(a)
```

The way I read this (please correct me)  is, for every `word` in `words`, compare it's length to every `word` in `words` and only "return" `y` if it is of equal or greater length than all the other words.

I get the error `local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`. Which makes sense to me but I am unsure how to modify the code. I want to only print the word with the greatest length.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: See, this is not an ideal use case for a generator, neither this returns max value of list. If you are to find maximum of list, there is `max()` available.

Comment: I realised, since the second longest word is still longer than the shortest word and will therefore be printed.

Comment: `in (b for b in words)` is simply `in words`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In first `for` loop, variable `x` is not defined. you have to define two `for` loops. then use `if` statement at the end. like this:

```
for a in (y for y in words for x in (b for b in words) if len(y) >= len(x)):
    # ....
```

I think python built-in `max` function is what you need:

```
>>> words = ["a", "ab", "abc"]
>>> print(max(words))
'abc'
```

UPDATE: for find all max size strings in list:

```
>>> words = ["a", "ab", "abc", "def"]
>>> print([i for i in a if len(i) == len(max(a))])
['abc', 'def']
```

Comment: I imagine that would then be the same as `for a in (y for y in words for b in words if len(y) > len(b))`. Yes you are right!

Comment: `max` is not what the OP looks for since `max` returns only one item, while the OP's generator expression allows for multiple items of equal length as the output.

Comment: @blhsing I update my answer for situation you mentioned. however I don't think it is what really HarryStuart wants !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modification, using `all()`:

```
for a in (y for y in words if all ([len(y) >= len(x) for x in words])):
    print (a)
```

**Output:**

```
abc
```

The `all()` provides the crucial semantics you're missing--it now reads as print every `a` in the list of `words` that exceed **all** other words in length.

Without the `all()`, even if you get rid of your error, you will not get the correct output you're looking for.

With a slightly different list:

```
words = ["a", "ab", "abc", "cba"]
```

you get:

```
cba
abc
```

Comment: Ahhh interesting, I didn't realise the `all()` method could be implemented like that. Thanks!